# how to pass jwt token into the header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I make web application using react js, node, express

when I login the error message appear says "No token attached"
now I need to put a jwt token into header how can I do that

this is my code:

```
import { webToken } from "../crypto/web_token.js";
import { responses } from "../classes/responses.js";

export const verifyRequest = (req, res, nex) => {
  try {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) {
      throw Error("no token attached");
    }

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

    const payload = webToken.verify(token);

    req.user = payload;

    nex();
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(new responses.Error(error.message));
  }
};
```

another code: web_token.js

```
import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken";
import { errors } from "../classes/errors.js";

const secret = "#########";

export const webToken = Object.freeze({
  generate: (data, expiry = "1hr") => {
    try {
      return jsonwebtoken.sign(data, secret, { expiresIn: expiry });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new errors.Logic("Internal error from the bcrypt hashing", "jwt");
    }
  },

  verify: (token) => {
    try {
      const data = jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secret);

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new errors.Authentication(
        error.message.replace("jwt", "Token"),
        "jwt"
      );
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: You need to post error that your are facing and where exactly it is throwing that error in your code? Also provide your routes

Comment: Can you show me your react code?

Answer (score 0):

here is the template, take a look

```bash
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "value1": "val1"
});

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/GetText',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```